# Microsoft Teams - Incoming Webhook Whitelist

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to set up an "**incoming webhook**" in my company.
My company have a firewall, and I have to ask to whitlist an IP / range of IP in order to be able to send POST request to the webhook. MS documentation about webhooks connectors: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using)

The webhook url look like: https://[tenant].webhook.office.com/webhookb2/xxx/IncomingWebhook/xxx/xxx

I have read the office365 documentation about ips:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges

But they are way to many ips.
How to find out which ones I should whitelist ?
Have any of you ever had this kind of problem?

Comment: Hi @Jeremie, You can use "*.cloudapp.net" address to send POST request to the webhook.

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "*.cloudapp.net" address to send POST request to the webhook.

Comment: Hello @mamatha. Sorry for this late answer, but I finally whitelisted the fqdn: [tenant].webhook.office.com